# Extreme pgfplots -- Improve 3d polar plot resolution and prevent "TeX capacity exceeded"

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

So I have this 3d polar plot describing an antenna's radiation pattern, generated with the data exported from the simulation program.
The spike in the middle is the main feature of the radiation pattern, but it should be more *rounded*.

This is caused by the fact that the maximum angular resolution is of 3 degrees (x and y axes are in degree). A smaller resolution (2 or 1 degree) causes the `TeX capacity exceeded` error.

However, I'll be happy to improve the resolution only in the proximity of the peak (-15 < phi, theta < 15), but I'm struggling with the data files.

[image]

The MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot,polar,units,external}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        colorbar,
        data cs=polar,
        ymin=-50, ymax=50,
        xmin=-50, xmax=50,
        zmin=0, zmax=31,
        xlabel={$\phi$},
        x unit=\si{\degree},
        ylabel={$\theta$},
        y unit=\si{\degree},
        zlabel={Directivity},
        z unit=\si{\dB},        
        point meta min=0, point meta max=31,
        unit vector ratio*=1 1 2,
        z buffer=sort,
        view={45}{30},
        width=20cm
        ]
\addplot3[surf, fill=white, mesh/ordering=y varies, mesh/rows=61] %
table[x index={1},y index={0},z index={2}]{8x8-ful-arr-good-3.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the data files are:

- [2 degree angular resolution](https://gist.github.com/afcuttin/b90881df080790003891)
- [3 degree angular resolution (used in the mwe)](https://gist.github.com/afcuttin/781ad3674363de6a4af5)

I'm looking for a way to improve the plot in the desired region using pgfplots.
Is there a way to combine the two files?

Comment: sorry, posted prematurely (pressed enter by mistake). wait some minutes for the full question

Comment: Done! question is complete

Comment: Btw, I already increased the LaTeX memory: `main_memory = 12000000`

Comment: If using LuaLaTeX is an option (it has dynamic memory allocation), your MWE successfully compiles on my system with either data file.

Comment: @PaulGessler of course yes, but with LuaLaTeX I get a `TeX capacity exceeded error` as well.
For the sake of curiosity, are you capable to compile the mwe even with a 1 degree resolution data file?
https://gist.github.com/afcuttin/ec591a704a9dfbe5392b

Comment: No, with that data file I get `!TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=100000].` But you are plotting _many_ more data points than you're displaying. Why not just cut down the data file to only contain the points you're really plotting?

Comment: @PaulGessler I agree, there are a lot of points at -200 which I'm not interested in. I tried to cancel them, but then the plot was inconsistent.
Is there a good way to get rid of them?

Comment: @PaulGessler btw, did you get my email?

Comment: Side note: PGF has a memory leak which causes `!TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=100000]` for huge mesh/surface plots. I am about to repair it. Workarounds are only to lower the resolution or to use `shader=interp`.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204218/pgfplots-closes-paths-in-polar-plot/204243#204243 (just for linking purposes and to have a non-github download link)

Answer (score 3):

You can filter out points that you do not need by means of `x filter` and/or `y filter`. In order to keep the mesh structure intact, you have to respect two items:

1. make sure that you assign `unbounded coords=jump`
2. make sure that points which should be discarded receive "nan" (and *not* an empty value).

Violating any of these items would destroy the mesh structure.

Here is what I get:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        data cs=polar,
       % ymin=-180, ymax=180,
       % xmin=-180, xmax=180,
       % zmin=-20, zmax=11,
       % unit vector ratio*=1 1 10,
        z buffer=sort,
        view={45}{30},
        width=15cm,
        x filter/.code={%
            % PHI:
            \ifdim-15pt>#1pt
                \def\pgfmathresult{nan}%
            \fi
        },
        y filter/.code={%
            % THETA
            \ifdim#1pt>15pt
                \def\pgfmathresult{nan}%
            \fi
        },
        unbounded coords=jump,
        ]
\addplot3[surf, fill=white, mesh/ordering=y varies, mesh/rows=37] table[x index={1},y index={0},z index={2}]{polar.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes:

1. I used your data file from [Pgfplots closes paths in polar plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204218/pgfplots-closes-paths-in-polar-plot/204243#204243) .
2. The `x filter` seems to have no effect... you may want to tune that stuff based on your data file.
3. The filters in my example work by means of TeX primitives, i.e. by means of `\ifdim<dimension1> <operation> <dimension2>`. Since the numbers in this context have no dimension, I have to append "pt" artificially. This approach has restricted accuracy and number range < 16384, but it works for this picture.
4. `\if<condition> \else \fi` is the TeX primitive for conditionals and `\def\pgfmathresult{nan}` overwrites the result with "nan".
5. There is a hole in some slice and I suspect your condition " (-15 < phi, theta < 15)" might need some modification -- either because I used the wrong data file or because it really needs different arguments.

References: see the pgfplots manual, especially the documentation for `unbounded coords` .